# Method parameters with exception handling

Tags: c#, methods

I'm obviously a newbie when it comes to C# and the following program is from a Charles Petzold book that I don't fully understand.  The parameter in the `GetDouble` method is a string named prompt.  Nowhere is this declared and I think that's what's messing me up.  I see that the Main method is calling `GetDouble` and is printing three strings to the console, but this whole thing looks weird to me.  Is this typical programming design, or is this not industry standard, but for purposes of showing how things can be done?  The book doesn't give an answer either way.  My fledgling programming self wouldn't pass a string to the Main method.  Can someone help straighten me out?

```
using System;

class InputDoubles
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double dbase = GetDouble("Enter the base: ");
        double exp = GetDouble("enter the exponent: ");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} to the power of {1} is {2}", dbase, exp, Math.Pow(dbase, exp));
    }

    static double GetDouble(string prompt)
    {
        double value = Double.NaN;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            try
            {
                value = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("you enter an invalid number!");
                Console.WriteLine("please try again");
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }

        while (Double.IsNaN(value));
        return value;

    }
}
```

Comment: prompt is a parameter and has to be supplied when calling GetDouble. And in your main method, GetDouble is indeed called with a string parameter. The string parameter is just not declared in advance, but within the method call. You could also first declare a local string variable, assign a value to it and then pass that variable on to GetDouble().

Comment: this is one along the lines of what i'm familiar with, and i think why the program looked so funny to me in the first place.

Comment: prompt is the parameter to the GetDouble() method. "Enter the base: " etc. are the arguments to the actual method invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nowhere is this declared and I think that's what's messing me up.

Wait, it's declared right there - in the header of the method:

```
static double GetDouble(string prompt)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is the declaration of prompt
```

`prompt` is different from other variables that you have seen in that it is not a normal variable: it is a *formal parameter* of a method.

Unlike regular variables which you initialize and assign *explicitly* with the assignment operator `=`, formal parameters are assigned *implicitly* by virtue of calling a method. When you call the method, you pass it an expression with the *actual parameter*, which acts as an assignment of that expression to the formal parameter. Imagine that the `prompt` variable is assigned `"Enter the base: "` before the first call, and then it is assigned `"enter the exponent: "` before the second call to understand what is going on when you call `GetDouble`.

Comment: this is the kind of insight that i was looking for.  when you're teaching yourself and you see several disparate examples of how to do the same thing it gets a little fuzzy.  only been learning for about a week, so thanks :)

Comment: I reread this and I think that this is an excellent explanation of what's going on. ++!

Answer (score 1):

The `GetDouble(string)` method does just that - it gets a double from the input.
The text that is prompted to the user is a parameter, because there are two different values to be entered: first the base number, second the exponent.
By making the prompt a parameter, the `GetDouble(string)` method can handle everything from prompting the user for input to returning the value.
The alternative would be to prompt the user outside of `GetDouble(string)`. Which of these two options is preferable is a matter of taste.

Oh, and as you've probably figured by now, this has nothing to do with the exception handling in the method.

Comment: that part I did know :), but i didn't want to make an inanely nebulous question and i thought adding some context might expedite the helping process from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it this way. It does the same but I think more understandable:

```
static void Main()
{ 
    string messageForDbaseParam="Enter the base: ";
    double dbase = GetDouble(messageForDbaseParam);
    string messageForExpParam ="enter the exponent: ";
    double exp = GetDouble(messageForExpParam);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} to the power of {1} is {2}", dbase, exp, Math.Pow(dbase, exp));
}


static double GetDouble(string prompt)
{
    double value = Double.NaN;
    Boolean incorrectValue=true;
    while(incorrectValue)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        try
        {
            value = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            incorrectValue=false;
        }
        catch 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
    }        
    return value;

}
```